# Downloading images from a link displaying them in a listview

Tags: android

I have a list where for each item i need to display a image. I am downloading the image from a link and displaying it but with i am facing problems to display them as the list gets populated by text first and then downloads the images later.Also another problem is whenever i go up or down in the list image disappears and download again so the images are gone when i come to to the top the list items

## EventTask

```
        public RecieveEventsTask(EventListActivity c, String critiria) {
        appContext = c;
        session = new SessionManager(appContext);
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        String id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);

        url = "http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/geteventlist?user_id=" + id;
    }

    public RecieveEventsTask(MyEventList c, String critiria) {
        my_appContext = c;
        session = new SessionManager(my_appContext);
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        // id
        String id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
        url = "http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/getmyeventlist?user_id=" + id;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(appContext == null ? my_appContext
                : appContext);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Events...");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    String filterResponseString(String r) {
        return r.replace("\r\n", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;

        try {

            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();

                responseString = out.toString();
                responseString = filterResponseString(responseString);

            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();

                Utility.showMessage(appContext, "Cannot Connect To Internet");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        if (responseString != null) {
            ArrayList<EventModel> eventsList = new ArrayList<EventModel>();
            ;
            JSONArray jsonArr;

            try {

                // Log.v("json", responseString);

                jsonArr = new JSONArray(responseString);
                // jsonArr = events.getJSONArray("events");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    EventModel event = new EventModel();

                    event.setTitle(jsonObj.getString("event_info_title"));
                    event.setDescription(jsonObj.getString("event_info_desc"));

                    // Log.v("logo data "+i, jsonObj.getString("image_logo"));

                    event.setBanner(jsonObj.getString("image_banner"));
                    event.setLogo(jsonObj.getString("image_logo"));
                    // event.setDescription(jsonObj.getString("event_info_desc"));
                    event.setCategory(jsonObj.getString("event_cat_title"));

                    event.setStartDate(jsonObj
                            .getString("event_info_start_date"));
                    event.setEndDate(jsonObj.getString("event_info_end_date"));

                    event.setStartTime(jsonObj
                            .getString("event_info_start_time"));
                    event.setEndTime(jsonObj.getString("event_info_end_time"));
                    event.setEventId(jsonObj.getString("event_info_id"));
                    event.setPhone(jsonObj.getString("event_info_mobile"));
                    event.setEmail(jsonObj.getString("event_info_email"));
                    event.setWeblink(jsonObj.getString("event_info_web"));
//                    
//                  logoDownloader = new ImageDownloader(event.getLogoBitmap());
//                  logoDownloader.execute(event.getLogo());
//                  
//                  bannerDownloader = new ImageDownloader(event.getBannerBitmap());
//                  bannerDownloader.execute(event.getBanner());
//                  
                    eventsList.add(event);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (appContext != null) {
                appContext.showEventsDataLoaded(eventsList);

            }
            if (my_appContext != null) {
                my_appContext.showEventsDataLoaded(eventsList);
            }

            // else
            // {
            // Log.v("check:","null");
            //
            // }
            //
        } else {
            if(appContext!=null)
            {
            Utility.showMessage(appContext, "Cannot Connect To Internet");

            }
            else {
                
                Utility.showMessage(my_appContext, "Cannot Connect To Internet");
            }
            // 
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Do anything with response..
    }
```

i get the image link in my setlogo and setbanner method

## Adapter class

```
    private final Activity context;

    private final ArrayList<EventModel> events;

    ImageDownloader imgDownloader;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView icon;

    public EventsListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<EventModel> events) {

        super(context, com.bioscope.R.layout.event_listitem, events);

        this.context = context;
        this.events = events;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(com.bioscope.R.layout.event_listitem,
                null, true);

        TextView title = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.title);
        title.setText(events.get(position).getTitle());

        TextView description = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.description);
        description.setText(events.get(position).getDescription());

        TextView category = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.category);
        category.setText(events.get(position).getCategory());

        Log.v("logo", events.get(position).getLogo());

        icon = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.event_icon);

        //imgDownloader = new ImageDownloader(icon);
        
        new LoadImage().execute(events.get(position).getLogo());
          
        
        //ImageLoader.displayImage(events.get(position).getLogo().toString(), icon);
        
        return rowView;

    }

    
    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
//              pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
//              pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
//              pDialog.show();
        }
           protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
             try {
                   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
          return bitmap;
           }
           protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
             if(image != null){
               icon.setImageBitmap(image);
               //pDialog.dismiss();
             }else{
               //pDialog.dismiss();
              // Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // icon.set
             }
           }
    
}
    
}
```

i am setting the image in my icon of list items

## Activity class

```
private ListView list;
    private MenuItem myActionMenuItem;
    private EditText myActionEditText;
    private TextView myActionTextView;
    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    // private Spinner spinner;
    private Button liveEvent;

    private ArrayList<EventModel> eventsList;

    private static final String[] paths = { "All", "Favourites" };

    private ArrayList<String> array_sort;
    int textlength = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(com.bioscope.R.layout.eventlist);
        
        

        RecieveEventsTask task = new RecieveEventsTask(this, "all");
        task.execute();

    }

    public void showEventsDataLoaded(ArrayList<EventModel> eventsList) {

        this.eventsList = eventsList;

        // for(EventModel e:eventsList )
        // {
        // Log.v("title", e.getTitle());
        // }

        EventsListAdapter adapter = new EventsListAdapter(
                EventListActivity.this, eventsList);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Toast.makeText(EventList.this, "You Clicked an item ",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                showEventInformaion(position);

            }
        });

        // RecieveCategoriesTask task = new RecieveCategoriesTask(this, "all");
        // task.execute();

        liveEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.liveEvent);
        liveEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(EventListActivity.this,
                        LiveEventActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



    public void showCategoryListDataLoaded(String response) {
        Utility.showMessage(this, response);

    }
```

Then in my activity i called the async reciver task to load all the data along with link and gave set them in my model class.

Answer (score 0):

You haveto set `ResponseCache` in your Main class while downloading bitmap:

*Like this:*

```
try {
   File httpCacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "http");
   long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
   HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

and

```
connection.setUseCaches(true);
```

http://practicaldroid.blogspot.com/2013/01/utilizing-http-response-cache.html

Comment: so where should i use the code as i have display it from my adapter class. @marven

Comment: Check the link i have given